# Paypal payment and .NET confirmation/check page

Tags: c#, .net, paypal, subscription

ello,

is there a way to pay for subscription and then after PayPal confirmation to redirect from PayPal to subscribers website to finalize registration?

Is it possible to use any of these?

Option 1:

1. Click on subscribers website on icon 1 month subscribe
2. Pay by Paypal Express
3. Redirect to website and confirm it has been paid with expiry date and confirmation code
4. Register account and finish

Option 2:

1. Click on subscribers website on icon 1 month subscribe
2. Pay by Paypal Express
3. Paypal generates unique confirmation code
4. Buyer would save that code or write it down.
5. Buyer would go back to the subscribers website and click our registration.
6. In registration there would be login, password and paypal confirmation code fields.
7. After clicking "register" button the there would be code which would query Paypal whether there is payment confirmation with that email
8. If success then finalize order.

Is this possible to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPal offers you the option to redirect back to a confirmation page. I would setup the .aspx confirmation page, and check to insure that the user is be redirected to the page from PayPal. That should validate that there payment went through. You can code logic in the code behind to confirm the referring page is PayPal, and if not then redirect them back to your home page. This setup would require very little coding on your part, and the only way they would be redirected back to your confirmation page from PayPal, is that they successfully made a payment.